# Illegal Number Format Exception in Java

Tags: jlabel, numberformatexception

I have this code, which pulls in a double value from an external method call, converts it into a String and then displays it in a JLabel.

My problem is that sometimes the value might display: 1.95000000000000001, and I want to reduce that to 1.95. When I run the application, it prints: Illegal Number Format Exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 if (query.equals("BREAD602")) {

            callMethod.findBread();
            totalPrice = Double.toString(callMethod.totalPriceMethod());
            totalPriceLabel.setText(String.format("%.2f", "   Totalprice to pay: £" + totalPrice));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 totalPriceLabel.setText(String.format("Totalprice to pay: £%.2f", totalPrice));
```